# Applying for jobs in the EU as a non-EU spouse

Tags: working-visas, france, eu-citizens, spain, non-residents

I would like to know if as a married spouse of a EU citizen, I am entitled to apply for jobs in other EU countries or if I am only entitled to apply in the country where I was granted a permit to live in.

Comment: Would you be living in the same country as your spouse, and commuting cross-border every day, or would you be planning to live and work in a completely different country?

Comment: applying for a job with the intention of moving to that country. together obviously.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply for jobs wherever you want but you can only work in the country that issued your residence card. If you find work in another country you will need to apply for an authorisation to work there (if it's only temporary work) and another residence permit (if you want to stay there more than three months).

If your spouse is moving with you, then that's simply a matter of obtaining the same residence card from another country, which should be reasonably easy. If your spouse is not moving with you to your new country of residence, you are on your own as far as visas go, which means you will need to qualify for a (typically much harder to get) work visa rather than a EU spouse residence card.

That's assuming you want to *move* to the other country. If you intend to stay in your current country of residence and commute every day/week across the border, you will still need some form of authorisation but I am not even sure something like that exists everywhere. As far as I know, EU law does not help you at all in this situation (there are many rules about *EU citizens* cross-border commuters but they don't need a residence permit anywhere).

In any case, your current residence card alone allows you to travel and stay for a short time in other countries but not to work there.

Comment: thank you! but simply applying for jobs is not an issue right?

Comment: @elijah No, it should be fine.